# QuickSort: What is wrong in this implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I implement again quicksort algorithm by hand. Here is my code. Below code is run infinity:

```
public class QuickSort {
        private static int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
            int pivot = (low + high) / 2;
            int pivotValue = arr[pivot];
            while (low <= high) {
                while (arr[low] < pivotValue) {
                    low++;
                }
                while (arr[high] > pivotValue) {
                    high--;
                }
                if (low <= high) {
                    int tmp = arr[low];
                    arr[low] = arr[high];
                    arr[high] = tmp;
                    low++;
                    high--;
                }
            }
            return low;
        }

        private static void print(int[] arr) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        public static void quicksort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
            if (low >= high) return;
            int k = partition(arr, low, high);
            quicksort(arr, low, k);
            quicksort(arr, k+1, high);
        }

        public static void quicksort(int[] arr) {
            quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // int[] arr = new int[]{9, 2, 3, 4, 1, 8, 7};
            int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 5, 4, -1, -2, -3};
            quicksort(arr);
            print(arr);
        }
    }
```

The wrong thing is:

```
    int k = partition(arr, low, high);
    quicksort(arr, low, k);
    quicksort(arr, k+1, high);
```

If I update again:

```
    int k = partition(arr, low, high);
    quicksort(arr, low, k-1);
    quicksort(arr, k, high);
```

I don't understand this point. Why some implementation see this interchangeable. Means I can use both case. But the first makes me infinity loop.

Thanks

Comment: Using a debugger, watch the range arguments being passed into the recursive calls to `quicksort()` and I guess you will see right away what the problem is!

Comment: @TypeIA I knew what data make it wrong. I just don't know how to explain why true algorithm I read online can use both way. but my solution can only use one.

Answer (score 0):

For sure debug can help but I guess problem is in case when

```
low == hight + 1 => 
pivot == low => 
return low == hight =>
```

next call quicksort(arr, low, k) will call again partition(arr, low, high);

Comment: Can you be more specific about the event chain? What happens, why and what does that trigger?

Comment: What exactly you cannot understand? Just take the algorithm from question and my comments and see what would happen for example for array [2, 1] to sort.

Comment: I don't get your comments. Maybe you should pair them with plain text. Explain what happens and to what this leads. What exactly is the problem, where is the bug? Just elaborate the answer a bit such that it is self-contained and easy to read, even for someone that doesn't read the question in full depth.